# Laravel: Form select not working with style / class when setting the default option

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, select

I am using Laravel 5 with Bootstrap.

When I use below, the class and/or style works fine:

```
{!! Form::select('mylist', [''=>'-- select --'], array('id' => 'mylist'), array('class' => 'myclass', 'style' => 'width:116px)) !!}
```

However, when I set $mylist as the default option for my select form (in my edit record page), the style / class is not working:

```
{!! Form::select('mylist', [''=>'-- select --'] + $mylist, $row->myfile, array('id' => 'mylist'), array('class' => 'myclass', 'style' => 'width:116px)) !!}
```

Please kindly advise me to achieve this.

Thanks,
Naren

Comment: Aren't you missing some single quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the correct format you should use

```
{!! Form::select('mylist', $mylist, $row->myfile, array('placeholder' => 'Select','class' => 'myclass', 'style' => 'width:116px')) !!}
```